# express file-upload getting error after deploying on aws.for local it works successfully

Tags: node.js, angular, file-upload

this is my nodejs backend file upload and save to database code.this works fine on local after deploy on aws it does't work.check this [error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1Too.png)
for more info i have changed environment.prod. no problem for other req though.

```
exports.create = (req, res) => {

try {  
if (!req.files) {
res.status(400).send({ message: "Please select image" });
}else
{

const file = req.files.image;
const filename = req.files.image.name;

file.mv(__dirname + '/uploads/' + filename, function (err,success) {
if (err) {
  res.status(600).send({ err });
} else {
  const url = req.protocol + '://' + req.get("host");
  const tutorial = new Tutorial({
    data: req.body.data,
    image: url + "/uploads/" + filename,
    creator : req.userData.userId,
    uploaderName : req.body.name,
    createdDateTime : new Date()        
  });


 //Save post in the database
  tutorial.save(tutorial).then(data => {
    res.status(200).send({
      message:"success"
    });
  }).catch(err => {
    res.status(500).send({
      message:err
    });
  });

 }
 })
 }
 } catch (e) {
 res.status(700).send({ error: e });
}
};
```

Comment: Please take some time to edit your question describing what exactly happened and provide relevant parts of the error. An error "screenshot" is not useful at all

Comment: basically i want to store one image and some data in mongodb. for image store i used express file-upload middleware. and now i am getting error for move file. in local machine does't get error. and if i remove middleware and try to store only data it works and stores in db. but error in somewhere express file-upload middleware. while mv file.

Comment: What is the error

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1Too.png  this is error

Comment: It's a ENOENT error, ie no such file or dir